# No me funciona el redireccionamiento cuando uso .submit() en JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios, redirección

Mi código es para usar una librería llamada croppie y estoy tratando de enviar una imagen cortada a un PHP, entonces necesitó darle un valor a un input luego de cortar la imagen y para eso necesito agregar esa información cuando sé dé click en el botón de enviar.

La cuestión aquí:

Estoy teniendo un problema al redirigir este formulario a otra página cuando doy submit, la idea es que cuando presione el botón de enviar el formulario primero no se envíe y agregue el valor al input y luego de eso si se envíe, pero no me funciona de la manera en que lo tengo, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

El formulario:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="procesamiento.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="archivoSubir" id="archivoSubir">
    <div id="imgEditando"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="imagenCortada" name="imagenCortada">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Y el script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#archivoSubir').on('change', function(){
            $('#imgEditando').addClass('ready');
            $('#imgEditando').croppie('destroy');
            $('#imgEditando').croppie({
                enableExif: true,
                viewport: {
                    width: 262,
                    height: 400,
                },
                boundary: {
                    width: 300,
                    height: 450
                }
            });

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#imgEditando').croppie('bind', {
                    url: e.target.result
                });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        });

        $('#form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#imgEditando').croppie('result', {
                type: 'canvas',
                size: 'viewport'
            }).then(function(response){
                $('#imagenCortada').val(response);

                // e.submit();
                // console.log($('#imagenCortada').val());
                $('#form').submit();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

como ya encontré la respuesta mi pregunta, aquí va la solución y porque era :D

Resulta que lo que estaba generando era un bucle y por eso la página nunca terminaba de cargar porque básicamente llamo un evento submit dentro de otro submit.

Para darle una solución a este problema, decidí usar una variable de tipo booleana que contuviera false o true, donde inicialmente la variable es false, pero cuando se añade la información al input este cambia a true y puede redirigirse (ahora sí, al otro archivo).

Aquí la manera en que queda el script finalmente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var enviarFormulario = false;

    $('#archivoSubir').on('change', function(){
        $('#imgEditando').addClass('ready');
        $('#imgEditando').croppie('destroy');
        $('#imgEditando').croppie({
            enableExif: true,
            viewport: {
                width: 262,
                height: 400,
            },
            boundary: {
                width: 300,
                height: 450
            }
        });

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imgEditando').croppie('bind', {
                url: e.target.result
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });

    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if (enviarFormulario) {
            
            this.submit();
        } else {
            
            $('#imgEditando').croppie('result', {
                type: 'canvas',
                size: 'viewport'
            }).then(function(response){
                $('#imagenCortada').val(response);
                enviarFormulario = true;
                $('#form').submit();
            });
        }
    });
});
```